# Name errors with lambda functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, anonymous-function

I am working with the following example. I wanted to run my code with `mu>=0.9` in the last line of the following snippet.

However, I am getting this error `NameError: name 'mu' is not defined`. It is already defined but I don't see the problem. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Where is it defined??? Why are you using lambda expressions here to begin with? Assigning a lambda to a name **defeats the entire purpose of a lambda and you should just use a regular function definition**

Comment: Where you define mu? 
in lines `ggpdf_c  = lambda B0, D0, error: gpdf(B0, mu=0.7, sigma2=error)` you do not use `mu` variable, but set `gpdf` parameter mu to 0.7

Comment: You should define `mu=0` before the lambda function calls. If you don't do that, Python does not find a definition for `mu` inside the scope of the lambda functions.

Comment: Note, `mu` is not defined anywhere in the lambda where you try to do `mu>=0.9`. Don't take this the wrong way, but I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings about the way Python works. Often, when people come from a math background they think programming is like math. There are superficial similarities, and math helps make you a good programmer, but programming languages do not work like mathematical formalisms. Also note, your question has **nothing to do with anonymous functions**, which you shouldn't be using tobegin with. This same error would happen with regular functions.

Comment: Are you aware of how to use the `def` statement? Note, this has nothing to do with your error. It's more of an issue of style.

Comment: @Brown what errors? That is not an adequate problem description, and as I said, it's really an aside.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
gpdf(B0, mu=0.7, sigma2=error)
```

is actually syntax for a function, assigning 0.7 to the argument called `mu` in that function, and the value of `error` to the argument called `sigma2` in that function.

`mu>=0.9` is not valid Python syntax for assigning to a keyword argument in a function call, but it is a valid ordinary Python expression. But for that expression to evaluate, the variable `mu` must be defined, which it isn't. But even if it was defined, I doubt it would do what you want: it would pass `True` as an argument to that function.

Comment: Well, the syntax is valid, it is passing the result of the expression `mu>=0.9` to that positional argument. It happens to be a *runtime error* because `mu` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, this comes from your typo in keyword assignment `>=` instead of `=`.  It is confusing because you don't hit it when `f2` is defined, only when it `f2` is evaluated (since it is hidden inside a lambda).

Here is a minimal example that shows the issue.

```
>>> f1 = lambda a: None
>>> f2 = lambda: f1(a >= 0)
>>> f2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: so how can we define the value of `a` to be `>=0` inside or outside the function?

Comment: `>=0` to a not a valid python literal. What is that supposed to represent?

Comment: The line `ggpdf_v  = lambda B0, D0, error: gpdf(B0, mu>=0.9, sigma2=error)` runs into the same issue that I show here, keyword arguments are not variables that can be manipulated.  There is a 1:1 correspondence between `f1(a=1)` and `f1(**{'a': 1})`, the fact that `a` looks like a normal variable there is syntactic sugar.  The reason that we get a NameError instead of a SyntaxError is because the expression `a >= 0` still means something (or would, if `a` existed).